# JRuby on Appengine: jar splitting not working?

Tags: google-app-engine, jruby

I need to upload a jruby web application to appengine, so I use these commands:

> cd my/app/path
>
> jruby -S appcfg.rb update .

This throws an error saying:

`Found a file too large to upload: "/var/folders/Qv/QvM5YWsvGP84UoFhrVmLyE+++TM/-Tmp-/appcfg5196464172432329417.tmp/vendor/gems/jruby/1.8/cache/jruby-jars-1.6.0.gem".  Must be under 10000000 bytes.`

Browsing around I found that I need to pass a `--enable_jar_splitting` flag like this:

> jruby -S appcfg.rb
>   --enable_jar_splitting update .

Still this command fails, with a different error:

```
INFO: Opening new file: /var/folders/Qv/QvM5YWsvGP84UoFhrVmLyE+++TM/-Tmp-/appcfg7137125152681466424.tmp/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-core-1.6.0-0000.jar
Apr 11, 2011 1:08:12 PM com.google.appengine.tools.util.JarSplitter run
INFO: Closing file after writing 9991985 bytes.
Apr 11, 2011 1:08:12 PM com.google.appengine.tools.util.JarSplitter createOutFile
INFO: Opening new file: /var/folders/Qv/QvM5YWsvGP84UoFhrVmLyE+++TM/-Tmp-/appcfg7137125152681466424.tmp/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-core-1.6.0-0001.jar
Apr 11, 2011 1:08:13 PM com.google.appengine.tools.util.JarSplitter run
INFO: Closing file after writing 9990346 bytes.
Apr 11, 2011 1:08:13 PM com.google.appengine.tools.util.JarSplitter createOutFile
INFO: Opening new file: /var/folders/Qv/QvM5YWsvGP84UoFhrVmLyE+++TM/-Tmp-/appcfg7137125152681466424.tmp/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-core-1.6.0-0002.jar
Apr 11, 2011 1:08:14 PM com.google.appengine.tools.util.JarSplitter run
INFO: Closing file after writing 1316596 bytes.

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Found a file too large to upload: "/var/folders/Qv/QvM5YWsvGP84UoFhrVmLyE+++TM/-Tmp-/appcfg7137125152681466424.tmp/vendor/gems/jruby/1.8/cache/jruby-jars-1.6.0.gem".  Must be under 10000000 bytes.
```

Seems like it's splitting something... but it's still failing.

Any ideas?

Comment: Note that I can boot up in dev mode running `jruby -S dev_appserver.rb .`